# How to restrict to particular city results using Places API android

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I had a requirement that if suppose the city is Hyderabad then using places search API  I need to get only Hyderabad places while searching. But I am getting only a few places in search. how to get all the places related to Hyderabad city. Please anyone can help me out.

> **I have tried the code:**

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
                    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "apikey");
                }

                final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autofill);

                autocompleteFragment.setCountry("IN");
                final Button closeBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
               dialog.show();
               autocompleteFragment.setLocationRestriction(RectangularBounds.newInstance(
                        new LatLng(17.387140, 78.491684),
                       new LatLng(17.440081, 78.348915)));

                autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
                autocompleteFragment.setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS);
                autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                        if (place.getAddress() != null) {

                            Log.e("Place", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId() + " , " + place.getAddress() + " , " + place.getLatLng());

//                            progressDialog.show();
//                            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

                          double  latitude = Objects.requireNonNull(place.getLatLng()).latitude;
                            Log.d("lat:", String.valueOf(latitude));
                          double  longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                            Log.d("lng:", String.valueOf(longitude));

                            String name = place.getName();

                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(PlacesSearch.this, Locale.getDefault());

                            List<Address> addresses = null;
                            try {
                                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String aa = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                            Log.e("aa:", aa);
                            String[] ad = aa.split(",");

                            String street = ad[0] + "," + ad[1] + "," + ad[2];
                            String city1 = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                            String state1 = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                            String zip1 = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                            String country1 = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                            String  countryCode = addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
                            System.out.println("countryCode"+countryCode);

                          placesearch.setText(aa);
                            //    progressDialog.dismiss();

                            dialog.dismiss();


                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Status status) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                        Log.e("Place", "An error occurred: " + status);
                    }
                });
```